# Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [subnet-057ba3df40f87da4e] in the Resources block of the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, subnet

I'm trying to create an EC2 instance in a VPC using cloudformation, when I run the following:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name stack --region us-east-1 --template-body file://file.yml
```

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation:
Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [subnet-057ba3df40f87da4e] 
in the Resources block of the template
```

known that this is the **yaml** file I'm using to create this stack:

```yaml
Resources:

  accessSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties: 
      GroupDescription: "new EC2 security group for HTTP and SHH ports"
      SecurityGroupIngress: 
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          FromPort: -1
          ToPort: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      VpcId: "vpc-09495a820716bff3b"
  
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: "ami-0022f774911c1d690"
      InstanceType: t3.micro
      NetworkInterfaces: 
        - AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
          DeviceIndex: "0"
          GroupSet: 
            - Ref: "accessSecurityGroup"
          SubnetId: 
            Ref: "subnet-057ba3df40f87da4e"
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: 
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            sudo yum update -y
            sudo yum install -y httpd
            sudo systemctl start httpd
            sudo systemctl enable httpd 
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref accessSecurityGroup
```

I'm positive that the above `VpcId`, and `SubnetId` exist, and I'm not sure what seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`The intrinsic function` Ref `returns the value of the specified parameter or resource.`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) Drop `Ref` since it's not referring to a parameter or resource, and the value is hardcoded

```yaml
SubnetId: "subnet-057ba3df40f87da4e"
```

---

Recommend trying the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) to see these errors inline while authoring templates along with autocompletion and documentation links:

`E1012 Ref subnet-057ba3df40f87da4e not found as a resource or parameter`

Comment: it sure did fix the problem, thank you, but I had another problem that I've defined the security group twice via ```NetworkInterfaces::Groupset``` and ```SecurityGroupIds```, so I deleted one of them as it was causing a conflict with the other. anyway, thanks man for your answer and for your recommendation. I'm sure it's helpful